# android create internal storage folder without _app prefix

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am using following code to successfuly create folders on internal memory, but adds a prefix "_app"! So if I create "aplications" folder, it will be named as "app_aplications". How to dismiss it and set desired name? Thank you

```
public class DirectoriesActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        createFolder(getBaseContext());

    }

    public static void createFolder(Context context){

            context.getDir("aplications", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //Creating an internal dir;
    }
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, any particular reason you care about the internal folder _name_?

Comment: Hi Marvin, yes, I have an embeded code that looks for that folder name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Java API instead of Android API:

```
try{

  boolean success = new File("data/data/com.sample/aplications").mkdir();
  if (success)
    // directory created

}catch (Expception e)
...
```