# Wrong name creating folder inside Internal Storage Android

Tags: android, directory, storage, internal

I m trying to create a folder inside the Internal Storage.

I m using:

```
 File mydir = this.context.getDir("PrivateFolder", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

When i navigate inside data/data/com.test.myapp I find the folder with a wrong name: "app_PrivateFolder".

How can I create a folder named Just "PrivateFolder" ?

Comment: You can use Java API. Please take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9499768/2442831

Comment: tried but nothing.. even if I try to create it manually and then i try to check if it exists.. the App returns me that the folder doesn't exist

Comment: Dont use getDir(). Use getFilesDir() and File.mkdirs() on the right path.